# SSL error while curl-ling due to which git pull may have stopped working (?)

Tags: windows, git, ssl

The actual issue is when I try a `git pull` it simply hangs.

So in order to check if there is connectivity to github, I opened my ming tty git bash terminal, and, tried to get github zen api endpoint. Here is the response for that...

```
$ curl "https://api.github.com/zen"
curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protoc
ol version
```

I am suspecting some error with SSL negotiation; perhaps some old cached certificate is making curl error out, and `git pull` hang...

How do I troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: (1) this has nothing to do with certificates (2) for curl see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938019/git-pull-push-unable-to-access-https-ssl-routines-seem-to-be-down and some of the dozen-plus Qs linked to it and the link to githubengineering explaining about TLS versions (3) for the hang versus error I don't know; if updating doesn't help, I'd get a network trace to see exactly what it is doing or not doing

Answer (score 0):

Like [@dave_thompson_085](https://superuser.com/questions/1317952/ssl-error-while-curl-ling-due-to-which-git-pull-may-have-stopped-working#comment1962946_1317952) said, it is not a SSL issue. Update git to the latest version.